# sql to dax - connecting 2 tables with multiple rows

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

How can I transform this SQL into DAX?

```
SELECT Tasks.ID, Tasks.ClientType, Tasks.EntityAccount, Tasks.Channel, Tasks.ProcessType, TasksTime.NrOfMinuts
FROM TasksTime 
INNER JOIN Tasks ON (TasksTime.[ClientType] = Tasks.[ClientType]) AND (TasksTime.[EntityAccount] = Tasks.[EntityAccount]) AND (TasksTime.[Channel] = Tasks.[Channel]) AND (TasksTime.[ProcessType] = Tasks.[ProcessType])
```

[image]

Comment: DAX isn't used to create relationships between tables.  Do you have two tables in a PowerBI model that you are trying to create a relationship between?  Unfortunately, such models don't support composite key joins at this time -- you will need to first create a single field that uniquely identifies rows in both tables that can then be used to make a relationship.  However, if you are willing to work in Power Query, composite key joins are supported there.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. They are in model. I've achieved thru Power Query editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the query editor in Power BI. You need to import both tables into Power BI then go to `Edit Queries > Home > Merge Queries`. Select your to tables and click on the columns for the relationship. If you have more then one relationship column you have to use `Shift + Mouse Click`. In the top right of the column name you will see an number, which indicates the first, second, ... relationship. In the end select your join and hit `OK`.